# Error while configuring CSS modules with webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to configure CSS modules with webpack but I get an error.

I have checked the other answers here on stackoverflow but none of the solutions have made it work for me so far.

I have added the loader as the docs suggest but it still shows an error.

This is my webpack.configuration.js file.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

The error I get is this.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./src/index.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
     - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:
       object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }
     - options.importLoaders should be one of these:
       boolean | number
       -> Enables/Disables or setups number of loaders applied before CSS loader (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#importloaders).
       Details:
        * options.importLoaders should be a boolean.
        * options.importLoaders should be a number.
        at validate (C:\Users\Arjun\Desktop\manpro\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:49:11)
        at Object.loader (C:\Users\Arjun\Desktop\manpro\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:34:28)
     @ ./src/index.css 1:14-150 20:4-31:5 23:25-161
     @ ./src/index.js

    ERROR in ./src/components/layout/Navbar.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./src/components/layout/Navbar.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
     - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid
```

update: I was able to fix it with this:

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        modules: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 33):

Syntax of css-loader options has changed in version 3.0.0. `localIdentName` was moved under `modules` option.

I don't know why option `importLoaders` is returning error if specified in inline syntax. But non-inline syntax is working, try to replace css loader configuration in your webpack config with this:

```js
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'style-loader'
        },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: {
                    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I was able to fix it with this:
"{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }"

Comment: Yes, that is also correct. But if you want to also specify different version of `localIdentName` than the default one, try to use my suggestion.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks again.

Comment: Lifesaver. New to react. Kinda lost with this settings. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue and fixed it with the below solution

```
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.<br>

 - options has an unknown property 'localIndentName'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals?, esModule? }
```

- In the latest version of react the webpack.config.js has
  `localIdentName` nested in modules.
- Move your `localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'` to modules by replaing `modules : true` with the below format

> ```
> {
>               test: cssRegex,
>               exclude: cssModuleRegex,
>               use: getStyleLoaders({
>                 importLoaders: 1,
>                 sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
>               modules: {
>                     localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
>                 }
> }
> ```

This should fix the issue

Answer (score 4):

```
test: cssRegex,
exclude: cssModuleRegex,
use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    // modules:true,
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
    modules:{
        localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
    }
}),
```

Use this code it's working for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with this code... `

### Write this code in webpack.config.js file

{
`test: cssRegex, exclude: cssModuleRegex, use: getStyleLoaders({   importLoaders: 1, sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap, modules: true,`
}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.